# Component must be declared when trying to access nested tables columns using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm having trouble accessing the nested table columns, when I try to execute the procedure I get the errors below. I have created a type called order_items which contains the columns below and have nested this type within my orders table, but unsure how to access the columns.

```
37/1     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
37/53    PLS-00302: component 'SUB_ORDER_NUMBER' must be declared
41/1     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
41/45    PLS-00302: component 'QUANTITY' must be declared
42/1     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
42/46    PLS-00302: component 'CONDITION' must be declared
43/1     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
43/47    PLS-00302: component 'UNIT_PRICE' must be declared
44/1     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
44/48    PLS-00302: component 'COST_CHARGE' must be declared
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE find_product 
(prod_no IN INT) AS 
CURSOR p IS SELECT 
            O.order_id,
            O.order_number, 
            O.billing_name, 
            O.billing_email, 
            O.billing_address, 
            O.billing_city, 
            O.billing_province, 
            O.billing_postcode, 
            O.billing_telephone, 
            O.billing_total,
            O.order_date, 
            I.sub_order_number "sub_order_number", 
            I.quantity "quantity", 
            I.condition "condition", 
            I.unit_price "unit_price", 
            I.cost_charge "cost_charge", 
            product.name AS product_name,
            product.description,
            product.category
            FROM orders O, TABLE (O.Items) I
            JOIN product ON product.product_id = I.product_id
            WHERE I.product_id = prod_no;
    BEGIN
    FOR p_rec IN p LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Order Date: ' || p_rec.order_date);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Order Number: ' || p_rec.order_number);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Customer Name: ' || p_rec.billing_name);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Customer Email: ' || p_rec.billing_email);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Customer Address: ' || p_rec.billing_address);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Customer City: ' || p_rec.billing_city);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Customer Province: ' || p_rec.billing_province);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Customer Postcode: ' || p_rec.billing_postcode);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Customer Telephone: ' || p_rec.billing_telephone);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Sub Order Number: ' || p_rec.sub_order_number);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Product: ' || p_rec.product_name);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Product Description: ' || p_rec.description);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Product Category: ' || p_rec.category);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Quantity: ' || p_rec.quantity);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Condition: ' || p_rec.condition);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Unit Price: ' || p_rec.unit_price);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Cost Charge: ' || p_rec.cost_charge);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Total: ' || p_rec.billing_total);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('------------------------------------------------' || null);
    END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('prod_no does not exist'); 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Operation failed  ' || 
        'SQLCODE: ' || SQLCODE); DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL Error Message ' || SQLERRM);
    ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you alias a column with a quoted identifier (like `I.sub_order_number "sub_order_number"`) then you need to exactly match that alias whenever you reference it. If the string between quotes is upper case only (no spaces) you can omit the quotes. All of the options below will work (this is an example with the emp/dept sample data.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT ename as "name",
           empno as "NO",
           job as JOB,
           hiredate AS "Fancy Alias !",
           mgr as mgr
           
      FROM emp
      WHERE ename = 'KING';
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('name: '||rec."name");
    dbms_output.put_line('NO: '||rec.NO);
    dbms_output.put_line('JOB: '||rec.JOB);
    dbms_output.put_line('Fancy Alias !: '||rec."Fancy Alias !");
    dbms_output.put_line('mgr: '||rec.mgr);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

My advice is to use aliases without qoutes - that always works, but if you want to make it more complex - hey it's your code ;)

Comment: Thank you didn't realise I had to use the quoted identifier, appreciate the help

Comment: You don't - it's ever "cleaner" if you don't I just updated my answer with more examples